# Elasticsearch: custom scoring with tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents of the following form:

```
{
    "content": "lorem ipsum...",
    "tags": [
        { "tag": "red", weight: 3 },
        { "tag": "green", weight: 1 },
    ]
}
```

I want to search for documents with a full-text search and change the score depending on tag matches.

Assume I am searching for the phrase `ipsum` and the tag `red`. The text search would yield a score of, say, `2` for the above document. The document also has a tag `red` with weight `3`, so I want the score to be multiplied by this weight for a resulting score of `6`.

My current approach is to use a `script_score`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { ... }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "tags",
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "key": "red"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * doc['tags']['red'].weight"
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "first"
    }
  }
}
```

The part that's not working is `"script": "_score * doc['tags']['red'].weight"`.

How would I need to write the script to access the weight?

Comment: Just found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439013/elasticsearch-influence-scoring-with-custom-score-field-in-document, but how can I use the score from that answer to modify my fulltext score?